# Haskell pattern matching with varying types

Tags: haskell

How do I make this work in Haskell?:

```hs
-- Throws an error when it tries to compile.
foo 'a' = "it is an a"
foo 0 = "it is a 0"
```

Individually they work:

```hs
foo :: Char -> [Char]
foo 'a' = "it is an a"
```

```hs
foo :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> [Char]
foo 0 = "it is a 0"
```

Comment: This can not be the *same* function, since for the function `foo` there needs to be an input type. What you can do is define a typeclass, and make use of *ad-hoc* polymorphism.

Comment: I'm curious why would you do that, but I don't think it's possible. Maybe create a [Sum type](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/sum-types), for example `data Foo = Foo Char | Foo Num`

Comment: @AntonHarniakou For no practical reason actually. I am reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions and I try if things work or not, and I thought the reason this one fails might be worth understanding.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks.